# Can't get envs from inside of docker container

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I have alpine based docker with preset env `$FOO`:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
ARG FOO
ENV FOO ${FOO}
```

I pass variable with `run` command from gitlab ci: `docker build --build-arg FOO=$BAR .`
Then I try `docker run -it container_name echo $BO_USER` and get BAR.
But I can't get this env nor from my application running inside nor via interactive shell: `docker run -it container_name /bin/sh` and `echo $FOO`
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, there is no `ARG FOO` in your Dockerfile, it should be

build

```
export BAR=my_user && docker build --no-cache --build-arg BO_USER=$BAR .
```

Where $BAR is variable that I assume is set on host

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
ARG BO_USER
ENV BO_USER=${BO_USER}
RUN echo "ENV is $BO_USER"
```

But you when you run below command, you should look for `BO_USER` not `FOO`

```
docker run -it container_name /bin/sh and echo $BO_USER
```

or

You should use single quotes otherwise bash will look for variable on host

```
docker run -it --rm image_name sh -c 'echo $BO_USER'
```

[image]